# Is it possible to flush all image module directories in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a way to flush all of the image directories at once? Perhaps using Drush?

Comment: You may be interested in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/is-it-safe-to-purge-the-files-styles-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this on my system, but make sure you back it up when you test it out yourself.

Simply delete the styles directory in your files directory.  They will re-create as they are loaded.

i.e. from the command line, from your web root, you would run:

```
$ rm -rf sites/default/files/styles
```

You may run into permission issues as those files will be owned by the web user. In that case, maybe you could have a form & submit handler in a module delete those files since that would be run by the web user.  That is another topic though.

Answer (score 3):

Also, from the command line, with drush installed:

```
drush image-flush
```

which gives you a drop-down of all catagories. Choose 'all'!

Comment: The code inside Drush to flush all caches is pretty simple: `foreach (image_styles() as $style) { image_style_flush($style); }`. You can also run this from /devel/php if you have [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) installed. I prefer this method or Drush over manually deleting files from the filesystem, because [image_style_flush()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/image_style_flush/7) also does some other things like invoking hooks.